# trying to make it all on one line

Tags: javascript, discord.js

As it shows in the image it prints the args on a new line for every word which i don't want. I am trying to make it print them all on one line.

```js
module.exports.run = async(bot, message, args) => {

  let errormsg = args.join(" ");

  if (errormsg = "") {
    message.reply("Command usage ``.error (description)``")
  } else {

    let error = message.guild.emojis.find(emoji => emoji.name === "error");

    if (!error) {
      console.log("Error not found!")
    }

    let updateChann = message.guild.channels.find(n => n.name == "private-commands");

    if (!updateChann) {
      console.log("updateChann not found!")
    }

    let errorEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
      .setTitle(error + " Leaf bot is having an error!")
      .setDescription(args)
      .setColor("#15f153");

    updateChann.send(errorEmbed)

    message.delete().catch(O_o => {});
  }
}
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xyroh.png]

Comment: `.setDescription(errormsg)` AND `if (errormsg = "") {` is an assignment, not a test  - you want `if (errormsg === "")` - Although  `let errormsg = args.join(" ");` with a test of `if (errormsg === "") {`  does not make sense either

Comment: Voting to close the question as _It's caused by a typo or problem that can no longer be reproduced. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a way less likely to help future readers._

Comment: `if (errormsg = "")` will set the value `""` to `errormsg`

Comment: How are the 'args' or arguments inputted into the code? Could you give an example of what they look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `setDescription` method on the `RichEmbed` class takes a `StringResolvable` as an argument. A [`StringResolvable`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/StringResolvable) can be a string, an array or any other value. If it is an array, it will be joined into a string, seperated by a new-line.

What you could simply do, is to make a new string from your array by using the `join()` method.

```js
const description = args.join(' ');
```

The `join()` method takes a string as an argument, which will be whatever you want to seperate each string in your array with.